# Attach a photo to SMS/MMS message

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mms, file-sharing

How can the Apple Photo App attach photos to MMS messages? While everybody assumes that there is no way to do it, is there any work around for this? Some fellows recommend using copy and paste. Has anyone tried that before? If so can you please help me with sample code? I have an idea which I'm not sure can work: if we have the copy and paste code, can we implement it in one method using `afterDelay` code or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I had a client request this as a feature in an app.  Unfortunately, Apple doesn't trust us enough to give us this feature.

We ended up having to use an intermediate service  to upload the photo and provide the URL as a link in the SMS. ImageShack and yFrog could be two such services (they have an API available), but it really depends on what you need in terms of security/privacy.

Comment: My pictures picked from the photo album built in app so I think your idea will not fit my needs.Any way thank you for the answer .